# Orderer service raft consensus leader issue

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, raft

I have a Hyperledger Fabric network with 3 orderer nodes and 3 peer nodes. The issue is that the orderer nodes tries to pick a leader indefinitely.

Config.txt file
[image: config.txt]

All of the nodes, have joined the channel successfully (all of the nodes returned the same response bellow)

[image: response when joining channel]

orderer0.fabric.net log
[image: orderer0.fabric.net log]

orderer1.fabric.net log
[image: orderer1.fabric.net log]

orderer2.fabric.net log
[image: orderer2.fabric.net log]

The issues appears when I try to install a smart contract and initialize the first transaction.
[image: smart contract issue]

Components:

- Orderer: **hyperledger/fabric-orderer:2.3.2**
- CA: **hyperledger/fabric-ca:1.5.0**

Answer (score 0):

try to modify your configtx.yaml like follow content:

```sh
    EtcdRaft:
        Consenters:
        - Host: orderer.example.com
          Port: 7050
          ClientTLSCert: ../organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/server.crt
          ServerTLSCert: ../organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/server.crt
        - Host: orderer2.example.com
          Port: 7050
          ClientTLSCert: ../organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer2.example.com/tls/server.crt
          ServerTLSCert: ../organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer2.example.com/tls/server.crt
        - Host: orderer3.example.com
          Port: 7050
          ClientTLSCert: ../organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer3.example.com/tls/server.crt
          ServerTLSCert: ../organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer3.example.com/tls/server.crt
```

you can find that all Port are set as `7050`,and then re-generate genesis.block

from your logs,raft elected was not success,all node are still pre candidate status